# Using hibernate.cfg.xml and JBoss managed datasource

Tags: java, hibernate, jboss6.x

I have a project using JBoss + hibernate, and **NOT** JPA (don't ask me why, just assume this way). So we're using hibernate.cfg.xml and hibernate Session. Well, I'm trying to make JBoss to handle my session, so I changed my hibernate.cfg.xml to something like this:

```
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory name="unitName">
       <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
       <property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>
       <property name="hibernate.format_sql">false</property>
       <property name="hibernate.connection.datasource">MyDS</property>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

And in my code I just added:

```
@PersistenceContext(unitName="unitName") protected Session session;
```

But when I run the application, it goes:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can't find a persistence unit named 'unitName' in ...
```

Tried changing from `hibernate.cfg.xml` to `persistence.xml`, but still using Session, and I got an error similar to this: https://issues.jboss.org/browse/JBAS-8815

I know, there is a workaround for this error, but my main question is: Can I use a managed Datasource with plain Hibernate/Session and hibernate.cfg.xml? What I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!